# Install python packages on OpenShift

Tags: python, openshift, package, simplejson

I'm trying to install python packages on OpenShift but I see a dearth of pages about the best way to do this. Can someone please suggest the best way of getting on say `oauth2` and `simplejson`. I've tried including these in the `setup.py`, but I have no idea whether these are actually available or I'll have to upload and point to the path. How can I do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Did you install `rhc` (made by OpenShift.com) ?
If not then see on OpenShift.com: [Installing OpenShift RHC Client Tools](https://www.openshift.com/developers/rhc-client-tools-install)

Now you can access server with `rhc`

```
rhc ssh
```

and then you can do as always:

checking python version (with big V)

```
python -V
```

checking pip version (with big V)

```
pip -V
```

checking installed modules

```
pip freeze
```

searching module

```
pip search simplejson

pip search json | sort # sorted result
```

installing new module

```
pip install simplejson
```

and other linux/bash functions

```
ls
ls -al
echo "hello world"
cd folder_name
mkdir new_folder_name
chmod +x filename
cat filename
grep 'hello' */*.py
history
nano filename
for x in */* ; do echo $x ; done
```

Comment: Thanks. I've managed to get some of the packages required installed although there seems to be an issue getting MYSQL-python installed. I get the following: ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser' and yet I cannot manually include ConfigParser to avoid this.

Comment: In Python3 it named `configparser` - lowercase. Try `python -i` and `import configparser` - you don't get error. And that's why `MYSQL-python` has problem. I prefer `Postgres` so I have no problem with this. But on `PythonAnywhere.org` I had to use `MySQL` and they show how to install external package with `pip` - https://www.pythonanywhere.com/wiki/UsingMySQL. Maybe it will work for you.

Comment: I've installed rhc and git on local machine (Win 8). But python is on the server, not locally (and packages I need on server). So neither `python -V` no 'pip -V' work. What to do?

Comment: Connect to server using `rhc ssh` and run `python -V` on server.

Answer (score 2):

Trying to install Python libraries via pip always results in `OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied` errors for me. Not sure if this is a change in OpenShift behavior or a some misconfiguration on my part. For anyone else who has issues installing via pip, `easy_install` consistently works for me (at least with the Flask cartridge):

```
[appname-domain.rhcloud.com ]\> easy_install simplejson
Searching for simplejson
Best match: simplejson 3.2.0
Adding simplejson 3.2.0 to easy-install.pth file

Using /opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages
Processing dependencies for simplejson
Finished processing dependencies for simplejson
```