# importing python modules in openshift

Tags: python, flask, openshift

I have flask application running on `openshift` and I am trying to import `requests` module in program. I have added dependencies in `requirements.txt` as stated [here](https://developers.openshift.com/en/python-getting-started.html#step3).

My requirements.txt contains following entries.

```
Flask==0.10.1
Requests=2.6.0
```

I got **500 : Internal Server Error** and upon `rhc tail` i am getting

> ImportError: No module named requests

Am i missing something ?

**Update** : There was mistake in requirements.txt it is == and not =.

Correct version of requirements.txt should look like this.

```
Flask==0.10.1
Requests==2.6.0
```

However i am still facing problem because on `git push` my log states.

> remote:   Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Requests==2.6.0 (from -r /var/lib/openshift/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/app-root/runtime/repo/requirements.txt (line 2)) (from versions: 0.10.0, 0.10.1, 0.10.2, 0.10.3, 0.10.4, 0.10.6, 0.10.7, 0.10.8, 0.11.1, 0.11.2, 0.12.0, 0.12.1, 0.13.0, 0.13.1, 0.13.2, 0.13.3, 0.13.4, 0.13.5, 0.13.6, 0.13.7, 0.13.8, 0.13.9, 0.14.0, 0.14.1, 0.14.2, 0.2.0, 0.2.1, 0.2.2, 0.2.3, 0.2.4, 0.3.0, 0.3.1, 0.3.2, 0.3.3, 0.3.4, 0.4.0, 0.4.1, 0.5.0, 0.5.1, 0.6.0, 0.6.1, 0.6.2, 0.6.3, 0.6.4, 0.6.5, 0.6.6, 0.7.0, 0.7.1, 0.7.2, 0.7.3, 0.7.4, 0.7.5, 0.7.6, 0.8.0, 0.8.1, 0.8.2, 0.8.3, 0.8.4, 0.8.5, 0.8.6, 0.8.7, 0.8.8, 0.8.9, 0.9.0, 0.9.1, 0.9.2, 0.9.3, 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.0.3, 1.0.4, 1.1.0, 1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.2.3, 2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.1.0, 2.2.0, 2.2.1, 2.3.0, 2.4.0, 2.4.1, 2.4.2, 2.4.3, 2.5.0, 2.5.1)
>   remote: Cleaning up...

**Alternate Solution**: You can SSH your application and can manually install package using pip as answered in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24572276/install-python-packages-on-openshift).

Comment: Are you using a virtualenv ?

Comment: Openshift uses virtualenv and i am too using virtualenv in development

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put two equal signs:

```
Flask==0.10.1
Requests==2.5.1
```

or

```
Requests>=2.5.1
```

or, as @Paco suggested,

```
Requests
```

Note: This is generally a bad idea to add a package without the release number. If a newer version is released and that release breaks compatibility, next time you run (directly or when building the project), it might break everything.

Comment: on git push log is saying
remote:   Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement (line 2)) (from versions: 0.10.0, 0.10.1, 0.10.2, 0.10.3, 0.10.4, 0.10.6, 0.10.7, 0.10.8, 0.11.1, 0.11.2, 0.12.0, 0.12.1, 0.13.0, 0.13.1, 0.13.2, 0.13.3, 0.13.4, 0.13.5, 0.13.6, 0.13.7, 0.13.8, 0.13.9, 0.14.0, ....

Comment: 0.14.1, 0.14.2, 0.2.0, 0.2.1, 0.2.2, 0.2.3, 0.2.4, 0.3.0, 0.3.1, 0.3.2, 0.3.3, 0.3.4, 0.4.0, 0.4.1, 0.5.0, 0.5.1, 0.6.0, 0.6.1, 0.6.2, 0.6.3, 0.6.4, 0.6.5, 0.6.6, 0.7.0, 0.7.1, 0.7.2, 0.7.3, 0.7.4, 0.7.5, 0.7.6, 0.8.0, 0.8.1, 0.8.2, 0.8.3, 0.8.4, 0.8.5, 0.8.6, 0.8.7, 0.8.8, 0.8.9, 0.9.0, 0.9.1, 0.9.2, 0.9.3, 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.0.3, 1.0.4, 1.1.0, 1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.2.3, 2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.1.0, 2.2.0, 2.2.1, 2.3.0, 2.4.0, 2.4.1, 2.4.2, 2.4.3, 2.5.0, 2.5.1)

Comment: Then use the last one availaable: `2.5.1`

Comment: you could also remove the `==2.6.0` part. It will download the latest version available. It is better to have version numbers, in case a release breaks backwards compatibility, but if you just need to do this once, you can do it.

Comment: I did ssh my app and manually installed requests through pip.