# How to obtain the trust-rate of an ocr output?

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract

Is there a way to get the `trust rate` of an OCR output that is produced by `Pytesseract` ?
What I mean by the trust rate is the correctness percentage of the OCR output.

Example:

```
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(editedImage)
```

For this text string I  also want to show the trust rate if it is possible.

Edit: I tried the `image_to_data` but I got an error

```
print(pytesseract.image_to_data(Image.open('test.png')))



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1536, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/home/caner/Desktop/Met/OCR-METv3/venv/tkgui.py", line 192, in convert
    print(pytesseract.image_to_data(Image.open('test.png')))
  File "/home/caner/Desktop/Met/OCR-METv3/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 232, in image_to_data
    return run_and_get_output(image, 'tsv', lang, config, nice)
  File "/home/caner/Desktop/Met/OCR-METv3/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 142, in run_and_get_output
    with open(filename, 'rb') as output_file:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/tess_2mxczh8n_out.tsv'
```

Answer (score 4):

My guess is that you're referring to `confidence` with `trust rate`.
There is some info regarding this on the repo of the pytesseract module [here](https://github.com/madmaze/pytesseract).

> Functions
>
> - **image_to_string** Returns the result of a Tesseract OCR run on the image to string
> - **image_to_boxes** Returns result containing recognized characters and their box boundaries
> - **image_to_data** Returns result containing box boundaries, confidences, and other information. Requires Tesseract 3.05+. For more information, please check the Tesseract TSV documentation

I think what you're looking for is the `image_to_data` function.

Comment: I have tired data=pytesseract.image_to_data(editedImage,lang="tur", config='', nice=0, output_type=pytesseract.Output.STRING   but I faced with a problem  FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/tess_3z2uj7ij_out.tsv'

Comment: Have you tried this maybe: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28741563/pytesseract-no-such-file-or-directory-error) ? It could be just a missing library.

Comment: I tried thah solution but not worked for me. I edited my question and the whole error message is written there. @neznidalibor

Comment: Hmmm, that's strange... Have you tried adding it to your PATH variable, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36625207/python-oserror-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory?noredirect=1&lq=1) ?

Comment: Yes I tried it but not worked again. The problem is with tsv files but I do not know where can I find them and add to the project folder @neznidalibor